# Altium - Complex keepout shapes in Footprint Editor

Tags: altium, footprint, polygon

Is there a good way to create complex keepout shapes in the footprint editor in Altium designer?

I'm attempting to create a large keepout that needs to be everywhere except two pads shown (to avoid validation errors).

In the normal layout area, there are a number of tools that make this easy (as described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuL1B08drxw) youtube video). For example, I could create a polygon and remove the pad circles, then convert the polygon to a keepout. I could also do some creative stuff with normal tracks in the following mode, but none of these are present in the footprint editor.

So it seems I'm forced to this mess of overlapping keepout shapes, which would be fine if I could combine them all into one, but I can't figure out how to do that either. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).